# Jade indentation inconsistency, Express and Node.js Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, express, pug

Express creates files index.jade, layout.jade and error.jade with 2 spaces for indentation, whereas Visual Studio's default indentations are 4 spaces wide.

Hrm. Well. I'm sure there are those who prefer 2 spaces, and those who prefer 4.
So why don't they allow for settings?

Answer (score 0):

We can change it right here in Options > Text Editor > Jade

Hurray!

[image: We can change it right here in Options!]